# How can I fill remaining space in Android layout when Admob is not available?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, admob

When no ads are available in Admob (for example if user has not an internet connection) is it possible to fill that remaining space with other Views ? That is, is it possible to adapt dinamically the Android layout depending on ads availability ?

I have tried using android:layout_weight, but it seems that Android takes into account the space of Admob View even if there is not available any ad at that moment (I use ads:loadAdOnCreate="false" in emulator to simulate this situation).

Any idea ?

Comment: by "fill that remaining space with other Views" you mean views that when the admob view is available they should not appear? Or you just want to resize your layout with no new views? If it is the second then @Gabe Sechan answered your question. If it is the first then you have to do it programmatically from within your activity onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

Set the visibility of the ad's view to GONE when its not available.  That will make it disappear and resize the screen to take it's space.

Comment: Thanks !And how can I detect programmatically that Admob is not available on onCreate method ?

Answer (score -1):

You can check in the API https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView

I think you can put a listener to know if the ad is loaded or visible. Check it: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener#public-constructor-summary

edit: this is an addition to the last answer

> Thanks !And how can I detect programmatically that Admob is not
>   available on onCreate method ?